# Breaking out of while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

```py
shoppingList = [('Carrot',2), ('Onion',1), ('Tomato',3)]
amountGiven = 12
for item, price in shoppingList:

    openMenu = True
    while openMenu:
        costumerPick = input('Please choose item from the shoppingList\n')

        if costumerPick == 'Carrot':
            print('That would be: ${}'.format(price))
            amountGiven = amountGiven - price

            
        elif costumerPick == 'Onion':
            print('That would be: ${}'.format(price))
            amountGiven = amountGiven -price
            
        elif costumerPick == 'Tomato':
            print('That would be: ${}'.format(price))
            amountGiven = amountGiven - price
```

I want to break out the loop after the customer chooses one of these options

Comment: Given the title of your question, you apparently know that `break` is the way to break out of a loop.  So, since you already know how to do what you're asking -- what is your _real_ question?

Comment: We expect you to do appropriate research before posting here, such as searching for  your question title.  See any tutorial on loops; watch for the `break` statement.

Comment: my question is where I should use the break command to end the loop?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have the boolean `openMenu` and the while loop is only entered if `openMenu = True` .

Therefore, one way to solve this is to set `openMenu = False` after each of the conditional statements.

You would have:

```
openMenu = True
    while openMenu:
        costumerPick = input('Please choose item from the shoppingList\n')

        if costumerPick == 'Carrot':
            print('That would be: ${}'.format(price))
            amountGiven = amountGiven - price
            openMenu = False

            
        elif costumerPick == 'Onion':
            print('That would be: ${}'.format(price))
            amountGiven = amountGiven -price
            openMenu = False
            
        elif costumerPick == 'Tomato':
            print('That would be: ${}'.format(price))
            amountGiven = amountGiven - price
            openMenu = False
```

However, it doesn't seem like you really need the while loop since your for loop iterates over all the elements in your shoppingList.

Comment: The thing that there is a for loop at the beginning, I tried all these cases and it didn't work. I think you're right for loop is enough

Comment: Great, if this is the solution you're going with, please indicate that this is the accepted solution!

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't understand your question. If you want to break from the while loop, when certain condition is met, use 'break' statement.

```
shoppingList = [('Carrot',2), ('Onion',1), ('Tomato',3)]
amountGiven = 12

for item, price in shoppingList:
    openMenu = True
    while openMenu:
        costumerPick = input('Please choose item from the shoppingList\n')

        if costumerPick == 'Carrot':
            print('That would be: ${}'.format(price))
            amountGiven = amountGiven - price
            break

        elif costumerPick == 'Onion':
            print('That would be: ${}'.format(price))
            amountGiven = amountGiven -price
            break
        
        elif costumerPick == 'Tomato':
            print('That would be: ${}'.format(price))
            amountGiven = amountGiven - price
            break
```

Comment: It says unexpected indent!

Comment: @user14363840: I edited the answer to follow proper indentation. Python is indent based language. Please read about indentation in Python langugae.

Comment: @user14363840: If either my answer or slumpyrat's answer solves your problem, please accept the respective answer. It will be useful for others.